# How to get zxid of a zookeeper server?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Zookeeper assigns a unique number for each transaction called zxid. It has two parts - an epoch and a counter. I could find the epoch value in zookeeper's data directory. However I cant find the counter. Does anyone know where I can find it?

In general, how to get zxid for zookeeper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out its pretty easy
  echo srvr | nc localhost 2181

Answer (score 0):

Also looking at the current status of zookeeper server can show the zxid which is answered in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106546/how-to-check-if-zookeeper-is-running-or-up-from-command-prompt). Firt i executed telnet:

```
telnet localhost 2181
```

Then send following data to server:

```
stats
```

and then received following information:

```
Zookeeper version: 3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT
Clients:
/127.0.0.1:54864[1](queued=0,recved=6030,sent=6033)
/192.168.80.1:55675[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
/192.168.80.1:54769[1](queued=0,recved=432,sent=432)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/35
Received: 7104
Sent: 7114
Connections: 3
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0xd0
Mode: standalone
Node count: 148


Connection to host lost.
```

As you see the zxid is currently `0xd0` in my zookeeper server.