# Error: com.sap.spark.vora.VoraConfigurationException: No ZooKeeper hosts found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, vora

While running the command `vc.sql(testsql)`, getting following error

> com.sap.spark.vora.VoraConfigurationException: No ZooKeeper hosts found

Zookeeper services up and running on all three nodes.

Error log shows the following:

> 2016-09-14 15:14:32,418 - INFO
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] -
>   Accepted socket connection from /10.78.1.240:46458 2016-09-14
>   15:14:32,418 - WARN
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught
>   end of stream exception EndOfStreamException: Unable to read
>   additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed
>   socket at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
>   at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-09-14 15:14:32,418 -
>   INFO [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1007] -
>   Closed socket connection for client /10.78.1.240:46458 (no session
>   established for client) 2016-09-14 15:15:32,429 - INFO
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] -
>   Accepted socket connection from /10.78.1.240:46832 2016-09-14
>   15:15:32,429 - WARN
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught
>   end of stream exception EndOfStreamException: Unable to read
>   additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed
>   socket at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
>   at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-09-14 15:15:32,429 -
>   INFO [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1007] -
>   Closed socket connection for client /10.78.1.240:46832 (no session
>   established for client)

Answer (score 0):

Just try go to Ambari and restart all services.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if Zookeeper server(s) is/are running

In your cluster manager (e.g. Ambari) check if the Zookeeper server(s) is/are running. Also check the status of Zookeeper on command line as discussed at [How to check if ZooKeeper is running or up from command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106546/how-to-check-if-zookeeper-is-running-or-up-from-command-prompt)

For example:

```
$ <path>/zkServer.sh status
$ echo stat | nc <zookeeper ip> 2181
```

If Zookeeper is not running properly, the issue is with Zookeeper and not with Vora. In that case check the Zookeeper logs (usually  /var/log/zookeeper).

2. Check if Zookeeper is known to Vora

If Zookeeper is running, check in the UI of Vora Discovery Service (http://:8500/ui) if an entry 'zookeeper' is listed. If no entry is listed on the UI, check the log files at /var/log/vora-discovery.

Comment: I checked the two commands for zookeeper status and its working but the UI of Vora discovery Service service is not displaying Zookeeper service.

Comment: contet of vora-discovery logs: [INFO] agent: Synced check 'service.vora-tools.VORA1.ad.company.com.9'
    2016/09/23 17:26:56 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'
    2016/09/23 17:27:14 [INFO] agent: Synced check 'service.vora-catalog.VORA1.ad.company.com.7'
    2016/09/23 17:28:50 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'
    2016/09/23 17:30:14 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'


Note: Here in this log, there is not mention of Zookeeper service

Comment: contet of vora-discovery logs: [INFO] agent: Synced check 'service.vora-tools.VORA1.ad.company.com.9'
    2016/09/23 17:26:56 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'
    2016/09/23 17:27:14 [INFO] agent: Synced check 'service.vora-catalog.VORA1.ad.company.com.7'
    2016/09/23 17:28:50 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'
    2016/09/23 17:30:14 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'


Note: Here in this log, there is not mention of Zookeeper service. Rest all services are getting synced in the log and also displayed in UI. Errors are not seen in the log. Is it related with jar issue?